# How can I inspect an attribute of a module without importing it

Tags: python

I am trying to write a static documentation generator for a UI-library for Python 3 (toga).

Within the project there are the subdirectories :

- `iOS`

  - `setup.py`
  - `toga_iOS`

    - `__init__.py`
    - `app.py`
- `mac`

  - `setup.py`
  - `toga_mac`

    - `__init__.py`
    - `app.py`

I want to iterate through the directories and get the value of the `__all__` attribute in the `toga_x` module. The issue I have is that each module is designed to be installed on that platform, e.g. the Windows one requires a Python package that installs on Windows, the Mac on Mac etc.

If I use importlib or `__import__` it fails because within each of the `__init__.py` files it will import the platform-specific packages, e.g.

```
PLATFORM_LIST = {
    'android': 'Android',
    'cocoa': 'Mac OS cocoa',
    'gtk': 'GTK +'
}

for module, label in PLATFORM_LIST.items():
    print(module)
    sys.path.append(os.path.join('../src',
                                 module))
    module = importlib.import_module('toga_'+module)
    sys.modules[module] = module
    _all = getattr(module, '__all__')
```

Fails with "ImportError: No module named 'android'".

There are lots of options, ast, pylint, compile, inspectlib. Which would be the best approach for getting the value of `__all__` without having to install all the dependent modules?

Comment: and what if `__all__` is dynamically created? (not necessarily that it will be different on different platforms but could be from more then a single assignment statement)

Comment: It's been statically declared in each of the packages, as a way of documenting which APIs it supports.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ast` to find a static assignment node in a python source file:

```
import ast


def get_declaration_from_source(text, name="__all__"):
    """gets a single declaration from python source code"""
    tree = ast.parse(text)
    #walk through each statement (more or less) in the module
    for node in tree.body:
        #if assigning to a single target (a = b=  5 is multiple)
        if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and len(node.targets)==1:
            target = node.targets[0]
            #if assigning to the name we are looking for
            if isinstance(target, ast.Name) and target.id == name:
                #use literal_eval to get the actual value, can raise ValueError if not a literal value.
                return ast.literal_eval(node.value)
    raise NameError("name %r was not found"%(name,))
```

can use `random` source file as example:

```
import random
with open(random.__file__, "r") as f:
    names = get_declaration_from_source(f.read())

>>> names
['Random', 'seed', 'random', 'uniform', 'randint', 'choice', 'sample', 'randrange', 'shuffle', 'normalvariate', 'lognormvariate', 'expovariate', 'vonmisesvariate', 'gammavariate', 'triangular', 'gauss', 'betavariate', 'paretovariate', 'weibullvariate', 'getstate', 'setstate', 'getrandbits', 'choices', 'SystemRandom']
```

Note that `ast.parse` can raise `SyntaxError` if the source code has a syntax error (might be able to raise other errors when compiling) and `ast.literal_eval` will raise a `ValueError` if the value isn't a python literal which as you have commented shouldn't be a problem, cheers.